# SpringBoot OAuth2 custom login page

Tags: spring, security, authentication, oauth-2.0

I am able to integrate Zuul server or Spring Cloud gateway with Ping Open ID service. 
The basic setup works well. 
Now, due to the multi-tenant nature of our platform , I need to customize the default login page so I can provide branding capabilities . 
I  have tried to override the default OAuth2 login page by overriding the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter as follows :

```
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/login").permitAll().and()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .anyRequest()
        .authenticated()
        .and()
        .oauth2Login(oauth2 -> oauth2.loginPage("/login")) ;
```

and on the Cloud Gateway ( using Webflux ) as follows

```
@Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain securitygWebFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
    return http.authorizeExchange()
                .anyExchange()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .oauth2Login(withDefaults()).exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(new RedirectServerAuthenticationEntryPoint("/login")).and()
                .build();
```

None of these methods work .

The "/login" is a GetMapping controller that attempts to render a simple HTML page with user and password fields. 
Any help is appreciated.

thanks